# How to delete a word next of last slash

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts, line-editor

I have the following path :

```
$ vim /path/to/some/where
```

If I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd>, It removes entire text to first space. The result would be :

```
$ vim
```

How do I delete just the word next of last slash with comination keys?

Comment: Since this is shell functionality it would be nice to know which shell you are using (`bash`, `zsh`, `tcsh`, `dash`).

Comment: `bash` tag added.

Comment: Technically speaking, there are *four* words next to a slash in that string...

Comment: @jasonwryan Edited. Remove word next of last slash!

Comment: possible Askubuntu question:[Deleting input back to the last forward slash](http://askubuntu.com/questions/539395/deleting-input-back-to-the-last-forward-slash)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd>.

From [bash documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Commands-For-Killing.html#Commands-For-Killing):

> backward-kill-word (M-DEL)
>
> Kill the word behind point. Word boundaries are the same as
>   backward-word.

Comment: Since Ctrl-H is the same as backspace, Ctrl-Alt-H also works for backward-kill-word

Answer (score 3):

You can type

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>

I don't know of a single combination that does what you are asking for.